# PHP MYSQL "UPDATE"

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I don't know why, but for some reason the code below is not working as intended

```
$SQL = "UPDATE characters SET
            name = '$char_name',
            status = '$char_status',
            gender = $char_gender,
            pos.x = $char_posx,
            pos.y = $char_posz,
            shards = $char_money,
            level = $char_level,
            exp = $char_exp,
            hair = $char_hair,
            color.r = $char_color_r,
            color.g = $char_color_g,
            color.b = $char_color_b,
            spawn = $char_spawn
            WHERE username = '$nick'";
        mysql_query($SQL) or die("ERRORCODE 04 - DB QUERY FAIL");
        echo "saved";
```

it's always giving me the "ERRORCODE 04.." meaning that the query failed..

FYI: setting pos.y db value to the char_posz is correct as the axes are different from the Form to the actual database

EDIT: code now changed a bit due to some comments, looks now like this:

```
$SQL = "UPDATE characters SET
        name = '$char_name',
        status = '$char_status',
        gender = $char_gender,
        pos_x = $char_posx,
        pos_y = $char_posz,
        shards = $char_money,
        level = $char_level,
        exp = $char_exp,
        hair = $char_hair,
        color_r = $char_color_r,
        color_g = $char_color_g,
        color_b = $char_color_b,
        spawn = $char_spawn
        WHERE username = '$nick'";
    mysqli_query($dbcon, $SQL) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
    echo "saved";
```

this is the error I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>               pos_x = ,
>               pos_y = ,
>               shards = ,
>               ' at line 4

Comment: Replace `die("ERRORCODE 04 - DB QUERY FAIL");`  with `die(mysql_error());` to know the exact reason for your query failure.

Comment: try using like `mysql_query($SQL) or die( mysql_error());` . Also dont use the deprecated `mysql_*`

Comment: if I shouldn't use mysql_* what are the alternatives?

Comment: this `color.b` looks wrong to me, i only see dots when i use joins ...

Comment: "pos.x" seems like a non-legit SQL fieldname

Comment: try `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*` which is deprecated and prone to sql attacks

Comment: Limiter: it is legit, but needs to be escaped with backticks in order to work.

Comment: You should better show the exact mysql error you are getting when running this query

Comment: so after all the comments, I've changed a bit of the code (I changed everything to the newer mysqli_* and I've replaced my errorcode with the exact one (mysqli_error()), (see code in editted thread above)

Comment: @Cerbion Could you show us the actual query result => `echo $SQL;`

Comment: @RahilWazir thanks but I already solved it (and I was later using `echo $SQL;` anyway) but thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put single quotes around all variables in the query

Comment: @Konerak, Nope he meant around the variables.. `$char_gender` .. etc

Comment: Ultimately, after all the changes I made, putting every value into single quotes was the key so that it finally worked. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: ughh seems it does not work completely yet, the script response with "saved" and all, but all values are set to 0 for my character...

Comment: nvm That had some compeletely different reason, problem solved.